# Calculating the intensity of an electromagnetic wave

Tags: power, energy, electromagnetic, watts

I’m a bit confused when it comes to calculating intensity versus energy of a wave.

If I’m given an electronmagnetic wave with an energy of 1 eV, how do I calculate its intensity ? I know intensity is usually measured in watts/m^2.

I'm trying to understand how deep an xray can penetrate water based off its intensity, but I only know its energy/wavelength.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> If I’m given an electronmagnetic wave with an energy of 1 eV, how do I calculate its intensity ?

You don't have enough information to calculate the intensity.

In addition to the energy received, you also need to know over how wide an area the wave front was spread, and how long it took to receive the given amount of energy.

Practically, when we want to measure the intensity of an EM wave, we use a device like an antenna or a photodiode. This allows us to measure the power received (rather than energy). And by knowing the effective area of the antenna or photodiode we can quickly calculate the intensity. If we want to know the energy received, we have to do a post-processing calculation (integrate the received power over time).

So a realistic problem would be if you know the received power in watts, and the area of your receiver in \$\rm m^2\$, you would calculate the intensity from those values.

It's possible, for example when measuring the output of a pulsed laser, to know the received energy rather than the received power. In that case if you really want to know the peak intensity of the pulse, you'll need to do a more involved measurement, for example with a higher-bandwidth receiver, or using auto-correlation, to determine the pulse shape before you can find the intensity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know that radio frequencies are often given with power output in watts. Using the same example of 1 eV, if it is emitted with a 40 watt power output, would it's intensity simply be 40 watts/m^2? does the energy of the wave (eV) even matter then?

Comment: @ajnauleau, it doesn't really make sense to talk about "an electromagnetic wave with energy of 1 eV". You can talk about a photon with energy of 1 eV, or an electromagnetic pulse with energy of 1 eV. Or an electromagnetic wave with power of 1 eV per second (a very very weak signal).

Comment: As for your radio source with 40 W output power, the intensity you receive from that source depends on how far away you are from the source (1 meter or 100 km makes a big difference) because the power spreads out as you move away from the source. And the radiation pattern of the source (is it emitting all the power in a narrow cone in one direction, or equally in all directions).

Comment: If the source is isotropic (emitting equally in all directions) then you can find the intensity at a given difference by dividing the total power output from the source by the area of a sphere around the source with radius equal to your distance from the source.

Comment: **it doesn't really make sense to talk about "an electromagnetic wave with energy of 1 eV"** - I'm going off of the bottom of the chart of this page where xrays are: https://web.pa.msu.edu/courses/2000fall/phy232/lectures/emwaves/spectrum.html and it's telling me that an xray's wavelength is measured as 100 KeV. Do I just multiply this by the time to get the power?

Comment: Those are photon energies. To get the total energy in a pulse, you'd multiply by the number of photons. To get the power in a continuous wave, you'd multiply by the number of photons and divide by the time it took for them to be emitted or received.

Comment: How do I calculate the number of photons? Is this done with V * A going in?

Comment: going in to what?

Comment: Going into the xray emitter and projected xray going through water for example, 1g/cm2

Answer (score 0):

Given that the question contains little information, I would assume that the question and its answer are as simple as possible.

If you have a source of energy emitting in all directions **equally**, the quantity of energy passing through an infinitesimally small area in distance *r* will be the original quantity of energy divided by \$4 π r^2\$. However, you also need some information about the time during which the energy is emitted to convert an energy into power.